# Reset two way slider using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am currently working on selenium project where i have to reset slider. The slider is two way slider and I am currently doing it like below:

```
def reset_slider_value(self):
try:
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frmPriceUpdate"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[5]'))
    )

    slider_first = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frmPriceUpdate"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[5]')
    slider_last = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frmPriceUpdate"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[6]')


    move = ActionChains(self.driver)

    move.drag_and_drop_by_offset(slider_first, -100, 0).release().perform()
    move.drag_and_drop_by_offset(slider_last, 100, 0).release().perform()

except TimeoutException:
    print('Timeout Reset_slider_value')
```

I am currently dragging it by offset using static value. Is there any optimal(dynamic) way to reset slider without entering static value?

Comment: Reset to what state/value? Can you add the link to the webpage as well?

Comment: The slider of this type. Left slider to the minimum value and right slider to the maximum value.
https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range